# Рефлексия событий с их подписанными методами

Tags: c#, события, рефлексия

Есть класс TrafficLight со свойствами, методами и 1 событием с подпиской на метод. Также есть унаследованный от него класс Model2TrafficLight, у которого есть конструктор, принимающий объект класса TrafficLight и, используя его, заполняет свойства и события для своего будущего объекта через рефлексию (тут как раз наследование гарантирует, что свойства и события обоих объектов существуют и они идентичны).
Проблем с заполнением свойств не возникло, однако хотелось бы узнать как аналогичным образом передать через рефлексию подписанные методы на события (например, где в коде комментарий "TODO", а не заново в конструкторе их подписывать по одному (т.к. в объекте класса TrafficLight уже все подписано).

```
    public Model2TrafficLight(TrafficLight tl)
    {
        // Заполнение свойств
        PropertyInfo[] tlPropertiesInfo = typeof(TrafficLight).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in tlPropertiesInfo)
            pi.SetValue(this, pi.GetValue(tl));
        // Заполнение событий
        SignalDurationChanged += SignalTiming; // !!! вот здесь хочу поменять так, как это делается с PropertyInfo
        EventInfo[] tlEventsInfo = typeof(TrafficLight).GetEvents();
        foreach (EventInfo ei in tlEventsInfo)
        {
            // TODO:
        }
    }
```

Comment: а зачем вы это всё делаете? Наследование, потом копирование полей

Comment: @tym32167 ну как раз, чтоб не писать в конструкторе все свойства предыдущего класса вручную (а их может быть 20, 30 и т.д.), то же и про события.. Просто со свойствами я разобрался в три строки вместо 20.. Теперь интересно, а можно ли с event так

Comment: не, я имею ввиду, какую задачу этим всем подходом решаете?

Comment: @tym32167 ну если кратко, то есть список родительского класса, в котором я хотел бы хранить объекты дочерних классов. Все бы ничего, однако изначально список заполняется объектами родительского класса, а затем эти объекты заменяются объектами дочернего класса, но дочерние объекты перенимают свойства у родительского. Например: был список светофоров с начальными свойствами, однако мы решили оттуда взять объект, добавить ему новых свойств (которые родительскому классу уже неведомы) при этом сохранив значения прежних свойств

Comment: @tym32167 Обнаружил тут существенный недостаток данного способа: если свойство ссылочного типа, то эта ссылочная связь утрачивается (т.е. это неплохой способ клонирования, который так многие ищут, хех.. но мне важно сохранить ссылочную связь, так что я ухожу от данного способа, однако вопрос все равно оставлю открытым, так как все равно интересно как через рефлексию передавать ивенты).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам спросил, сам ответил:

```
        EventInfo[] tlEventsInfo = typeof(TrafficLight).GetEvents(BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach(EventInfo ei in tlEventsInfo)
        {
            FieldInfo fi = typeof(TrafficLight).GetField(ei.Name,
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | 
                BindingFlags.Public); // Получаем поле делегата через имя события (ведь
                                      // делегат по-сути поле и относится к Fields класса)
            Delegate d = (Delegate)fi.GetValue(tl); // Приводим поле объекта tl к делегату
            ei.AddEventHandler(this, d); // Добавляем полученный делегат текущему объекту 
        }
```